# «Похоже, что...» Нужно ли тут «что»?

Tags: вводные-слова, союзы

> Похоже, что меня либо разыгрывают, либо я все еще сплю.

Будет ли ошибкой, если оставить тут «что»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Диссонанс связан здесь не с присутствием "что", а с неточным порядком слов: "меня" может относиться только *к одной* из альтернатив при конструкции **либо... либо** (ср. *меня либо разыгрывают, либо отказываются будить*). Исправить можно перестановкой:

> Похоже, что либо *меня* разыгрывают, либо я все еще сплю.

Answer (score 2):

**Возможны два варианта:**

(1)  **Похоже, что** **либо** меня  разыгрывают, **либо** я все еще сплю. Это сложное предложение с подчинительной (союз ЧТО) и сочинительной (союзы ЛИБО...ЛИБО) связью.

(2) **Похоже,**  **либо** меня разыгрывают, **либо** я все еще сплю. Это сложное предложение с сочинительной связью (союзы ЛИБО...ЛИБО) и вводным словом ***похоже***.

**Примеры с подчинительной и сочинительной связью:**

Односельчане, кто был с ним в роте, **говорили, что либо** в плен он попал, **либо** погиб, а только тела не нашли. [Александр Солженицын. Матренин двор (1960)]

― Ей **показалось, что либо** зоолог со зла сострил, **либо** она недослышала. [Ю. Домбровский. Рождение мыши (1951-1956)]

Answer (score 1):

Судя по метке "вводные слова", Вас смутило сочетание вводного слова и союза "что". Дело в том, что в данном случае "похоже" не является вводным словом. Такую конструкцию нужно рассматривать как СПП с союзом "что".

Если убрать "что", получим предложение с вводным словом "похоже".

В любом случае, как заметил Alex_ander, порядок слов нужно  изменить.